# Select the next matching class/element when not immediately placed after original selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I think I've almost got it, but not there quite...

I want to select the a.rate-button out of this HTML only when an element one level up and two levels down in the DOM contains a certain string. I know that this is stretching the limits of a jQuery selector but it's just for fun and not production.

HTML:

```
<div class="comment">

    <div class="submitted">
        <a href="#" title="View user profile.">Blow, Jo</a>  
    </div><!-- CLASS submitted -->

    <div class="content">
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
  </div><!-- CLASS content -->

      <ul class="links">
        <li class="comment_delete first"><a href="/comment/delete/1204">delete</a></li>
            <li class="comment_edit"><a href="/comment/edit/1204">edit</a></li>
            <li class="flag_content_add">hippo</li>
            <li class="rate_thumbup_comments last">
                <span>
                    <div class="rate-widget-1 rate-widget clear-block rate-average">
                        <a class="rate-button" rel="nofollow" href="#">up</a>
                        <div class="rate-info">1 person likes this.</div>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

The jQuery selector I've got thus far:

```
$('.submitted a:contains("Blow")').parent().parent().next('.links .rate_thumbup_comments .rate-widget').find('a').css('display', 'none');
```

So, to reiterate: I want to select the  tag inside div.rate-widget which is inside li.rate_thumbup_comments only when container div.submitted has an  with a string inside it of "Blow". All of this is within the container div.comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work with the html you provided:

```
$('.submitted a:contains("Blow")').parent().parent().children('.links').find('.rate-button').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: thanks! that's super! i think i have to look up .children() and .parent() ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, for example, you want to hide all rating widgets for comments for a specific user. Correct me if i'm wrong.

```
$('.submitted a:contains("Blow")').closest(".comment").find('.rate-widget a').hide();
```

Is that what you are essentially trying to do?

`.next()` only selects the very next element, and only if it matches the selector if one is passed in. If you need to select an element that isn't immediately next, use `.nextUntil(targetselector).next()`, or in you case, `.nextUntil(".links").next()`

Comment: yes, that is what i am trying to do essentially. .nextUntil() is the ticket! :)